# Socket.io with node js and mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, socket.io, ejs

I am implmenting the when from client side entry inserted in db then i want to get notification in admin panel using node js mysql and socket.io

but in socket.io i didnt get like that the mysql event listner to get the listner when from client side entry is inserted in db and how to get trigger in Admin panel is the entry is inserted and showing the notification

Comment: wha's the question?

Comment: @Kurohige how can i get event of when record inserted into DB from client side and how can i get Admin panel there is new entry is inserted i want to show asa notification in admin panel

Comment: on client post successfully send an emit listened by admin and show the notification